# Net, which fans out, cannot be assigned more than one value

Tags: verilog, quartus, digital-design

I am trying to design an 8-bit multiplier based on 4-bit multiplier. so this is my code:

```
module _8bit_multiply(a, b, q);

input [7:0] a;
input [7:0] b;

output [15:0] q;

wire [7:0] q0;
wire [7:0] q1;
wire [11:0] q2;
wire [11:0] q3;
wire [7:0] x0;
wire [11:0] x1;
wire [7:0] sum0;
wire [12:0] sum1;
wire [12:0] sum2;
wire co0;
wire co1;
wire temp;

_4bit_multiply m1(a[3:0], b[3:0], q0);

assign q[3:0] = q0[3:0];
assign x0[3:0] = q0[7:4];

_4bit_multiply m2(a[7:4], b[3:0], q1);

nbit_adder s1(x0, q1, 0, sum0, co0);

_4bit_multiply m3(a[3:0], b[7:4], q2);
_4bit_multiply m4(a[7:4], b[7:4], x1);

assign q3[11:4] = x1[7:0];

nbit_adder s2(q2, q3, 0, sum1, co1);

nbit_adder s3(sum0, sum1, co0, sum2, temp);
nbit_adder s4(sum2, 0, co1, sum2, temp);

assign q[15:4] = sum2[12:0];

endmodule
```

then I get this error:

> Error (12014): Net "sum2[11]", which fans out to "q[15]", cannot be
> assigned more than one value
>
> Error (12015): Net is fed by "nbit_adder:s3|s[11]"  Error (12015):
>
> Net is fed by "nbit_adder:s4|s[11]"

And more than like this. what should I do ?

Comment: You haven't submitted an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (what are `nbit_adder` and `_4bit_multiply`?), but this doesn't look right: `nbit_adder s4(sum2, 0, co1, sum2, temp);` - `sum2` appears twice.

Comment: Your code woukld have been easier to understand had you used _named mapping_ instead of _ordered mapping_ for your instantiations. Never use ordered mapping; it is the biggest sin in HDL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same variable is the output of multiple modules in your code. Basically you're doing this:

```
assign sum2 = 1;
assign sum2 = 0;
```

So Quartus doesn't know what to do.